# Heroku Gradle Deployment. error. Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I feel like this is a .gitIgnore problem. I keep trying to upload my Spring Boot repository to Heroku from the command line and I keep getting this output

```
  symbol:   variable Access
remote:          location: class V1HitsDB
remote:        /tmp/build_baef3c14/src/main/java/com/h/db/V1HitsDB.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
remote:                String AWS_ACCESS_KEY = Access.AWSAccessKeyID;
remote:                                        ^
remote:          symbol:   variable Access
remote:          location: class V1HitsDB
remote:        Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
remote:        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
remote:        31 errors
remote:        :compileJava FAILED
```

Any idea what this is? Everything works perfectly fine on my machine (typical right ?) I have never had this problem with my other repositories. It's happening for all the methods where I use access keys from - which points to gitignore. my repository is https://github.com/Hart87/Mephesto

Comment: In case he deprecated thing comes up - likely for aws - I uploaded the same thing last week to heorku without issue. That’s what leads me to believe it’s gitignore

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `.gitignore` problem.  It is not even a deprecation problem.

It is a Java compilation error.  Your code is trying to use a class called `Access` and the compiler can't find it.

I looked at the source code for your `V1HitsDB` and it is importing a class called `com.h.Access`.  But your repo doesn't contain an "Access.java" file at the path "Mephesto/src/main/java/com/h/".

---

> I uploaded the same thing last week to Heroku without issue.

According to the commit history, you have made a few changes to your repo since last week.  Try deploying the version of your codebase that was current when it last worked.